# Returning number of results FIND method (vba)

Tags: vba, excel

my first message here so thanks in advance for your help.

Any idea how to get the number of results after applying the FIND function in vba?
I have a code that loop through on a spreadsheet (it looks for the whole word: `LookAt:=xlWhole`) and it returns and X number of results. 
I need that number as I subsequently need to put values is as many rows as the number of findings returned by the find method.

Editing to add an example.

```
.find(what:="Stackoverflow is great", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

let's pretend it finds 10 matches in the sheet, any way to be able to get that 10?

Comment: Can the word occur **twice** within a single cell ??

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A:Z, "Stackoverflow is great")`

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - The OP is using `LookAt:=xlWhole`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) can utilize the native worksheet [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) for this.

```
dim x as long, str as string
str = "Stackoverflow is great"
with worksheets("sheet1")
    x = worksheetfunction.countif(.usedrange.cells, str)
end with
debug.print x
```